# How do I prevent a fixed cover background image resizing on a mobile device

Tags: html, css

I would like to have a full screen, fixed, responsive background image in the header for a website. I have some css which works fine on desktop browsers, but on chrome on android, scrolling through the website results in the image moving/resizing when the browser address bar is shown/hidden.

Currently I'm using 100vh for the height of the header, with `background-attachment: fixed` and `background-size: cover`. Based on what I read at the following link, 100vh should always be sized as if the address bar is hidden. https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/12/url-bar-resizing

I've also tried using javascript to get the initial viewport height, and setting the header height to this value. It doesn't seem to work either.

Here is a very simple example, which I've also uploaded to an [S3 bucket](http://mobilecsstest20200921.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/) for ease of viewing on mobile:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      html,
      body {
        margin: 0;
      }

      .background {
        background-image: url(./image.jpg);
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        height: 100vh;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header class="background"></header>
    <h1>Should not resize on mobile scroll</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can use `background-size: 100%;` to resize the background-image in all device

Answer (score 0):

Give your `.background` element an absolute position and add a margin to the `<h1>`:

```html
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        html,
        body {
            margin: 0;
        }

        .background {
            background-image: url(./image.jpg);
            background-attachment: fixed;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
            height: 100vh;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
        }

        h1 {
            margin-top: 100vh;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <header class="background"></header>
    <h1>Should not resize on mobile scroll</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: this still triggers a resize of the image when scrolling on android chrome

Comment: Interesting. I’ll see if I can figure that one out.